# How to automatically update the timespamps of parent model when a relationship is being created or removed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

In Laravel a model that has a `belongs to` relationship to another, also has a `<parent>_id` field on its table that points to the `id` of the parent. When that model is being associated to another the `updated_at` timespamp naturally gets updated, as the value of the `<parent>_id` field changes.

The parent model though, the one with the `has many` relationship, doesn’t have any fields that change when it becomes or stops being related to a child model, so its `updated_at` timespamp doesn’t change.

What I want, is both the parent and the child models to automatically update their `updated_at` timespamps every time a relationship between the two gets created or removed. What is the proper way to achieve this?

I have already looked into the [touches](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps) property, which causes the timestamp of the parent to get updated automatically when the child gets modified. But this only works when a new relationship is being created and not when an old one is being removed. And also, this will update the timestamp of the parent at the change of any field, not just of the `<parent>_id` and that's something that I don't actually want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [touch](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_touchhttp://) method provided by Eloquent for this purpose for updating parent's updated_at timestamp.

```
$parent->touch(); //will update updated_at
```

If I haven't misunderstood, I can't think of a way to "automatically" do this except for calling this inline when needed or using the appropriate [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) on the child (eg. created and deleted or creating and deleting) for touching parent's timestamp.

Comment: I hoped that there would be a way to do this automatically, but after looking around for a while seems like that you are right. Since this is the only answer I’m going to mark it as accepted. So, looks like I’ll have to manually call the `touch` method every time the relationship is updated.

Answer (score 16):

Taken from the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps).

## Touching Parent Timestamps

When a model `belongsTo` or `belongsToMany` another model, such as a `Comment` which belongs to a  `Post`, it is sometimes helpful to update the parent's timestamp when the child model is updated. For example, when a `Comment` model is updated, you may want to automatically "touch" the  `updated_at` timestamp of the owning `Post`. Eloquent makes it easy. Just add a `touches` property containing the names of the relationships to the child model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model {

    /**
     * All of the relationships to be touched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     protected $touches = ['post'];

    /**
     * Get the post that the comment belongs to.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    } }
```

Now, when you update a `Comment`, the owning `Post` will have its `updated_at` column updated as well, making it more convenient to know when to invalidate a cache of the `Post` model:

```
$comment = App\Comment::find(1);

$comment->text = 'Edit to this comment!';

$comment->save();
```

## Update

The delete method on a model does update the owners timestamps
method is taken from the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php

To update manually you could run `$this->touchOwners();`

```
public function delete()
{
    if (is_null($this->getKeyName())) {
        throw new Exception('No primary key defined on model.');
    }

    // If the model doesn't exist, there is nothing to delete so we'll just return
    // immediately and not do anything else. Otherwise, we will continue with a
    // deletion process on the model, firing the proper events, and so forth.
    if (! $this->exists) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->fireModelEvent('deleting') === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // Here, we'll touch the owning models, verifying these timestamps get updated
    // for the models. This will allow any caching to get broken on the parents
    // by the timestamp. Then we will go ahead and delete the model instance.
    $this->touchOwners();

    $this->performDeleteOnModel();

    $this->exists = false;

    // Once the model has been deleted, we will fire off the deleted event so that
    // the developers may hook into post-delete operations. We will then return
    // a boolean true as the delete is presumably successful on the database.
    $this->fireModelEvent('deleted', false);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please read the last paragraph of the question, that's exactly what I initially tried and as I said it only works when a new relationship is being created but not when an old one is being removed.

Comment: The delete method will update the parent model on deleting. See edit the delete method from Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php